# Performing a Specific Function for One Column For The First 12 Rows?

Tags: r, function, global, environment, divide

This is easy, but for some reason I'm having trouble with it. I have a set of `Data` like this:

```
File     Trait      Temp   Value    Rep
PB       Mortality  16     52.2     54
PB       Mortality  17     21.9     91
PB       Mortality  18     15.3     50
...
```

And it goes on like that for 36 rows. What I need to do is divide the `Value` column by `100` in only the first 12 rows. I did:

```
NewData <- Data[1:12,4]/100
```

to try and create a new data frame without changing the old data. When I do this it divides the fourth column, but saves only the fourth column (rows 1-12) as a `Values` in the Global Environment by itself, not as `Data` with the rest of the rows/columns in the original set. Overall, I'm trying to fit the `NewData` in a `nls` function, so I need to save the modified data with the rest of the data, and not as a separate value.  Is there a way for me to modify the first 12 rows without having R save it as a value?

Comment: Perhaps you want `drop=FALSE`, `Data[1:12,4, drop = FALSE]/100`

Answer (score 1):

Consider copying the dataframe and then updating column at select rows:

```
NewData <- Data
NewData$Value[1:12] <- NewData$Value[1:12]/10
# NewData[1:12,4] <- NewData[1:12,4]/10           ' ALTERNATE EQUIVALENT
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
newdata <- data[1:12,] %>% mutate(newV = VALUE/100)
newdata$Value = newdata$newV
newdata = newdata %>% select(-newV)
```

then you can do

```
full_data = rbind(newdata,data[13:36,])
```

Comment: I'm really curious as to what "%>%" is aimed to do, because R doesn't seem to like it or understand. What is that suppose to do. (I should have warned you, I am very much a newbie). Also, "Library(dplyr)" doesn't seem to work either. R thinks it is a package

Comment: Once you get used to the syntax, most data manipulation tasks become very easy. It's called the "pipe" syntax and it is used in the dplyr package. It just means that the preceding thing gets fed into the next thing.

Comment: dplyr is a package. you need to install it using install.packages("dplyr"), and then load the library.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but it didn't edit what I wanted to. It kept the values that I was trying to divide by 100 the same as in the original data. Thanks though! :)

Comment: I edited it. It's not the most elegant answer for sure, but it works

Comment: This will edit all of the values, not just the values in column 4. That means that all my other values will be divided by 100, which will not fit well with the nls function when I combined this with the other data [13:36]. If I try [1:12,4] R insists that it is the wrong dimensions. Thank you for your help, but I don't think this is the answer.